# Como separar o nome dos pacotes na árvore de diretórios do Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, diretório, intellij-idea

Estou utilizando o Intellij IDEA para programar em Java e quero criar vários pacotes um dentro do outro, onde cada um deles conterá classes e outros tipos de arquivos.

O problema é que ao criar os pacotes pelo IDEA, eles ficam juntos na árvore de diretórios, sendo impossível criar uma classe `.java` no pacote anterior. Exemplo:

```
veiculo.carro.roda
```

Eu gostaria de criar uma classe no pacote `carro` porém não posso pois, os pacotes ficam juntos e o IDEA sempre cria a classe no último pacote, que nesse caso seria o pacote `roda`.

Imagem do meu Intellij IDEA (estou usando a última versão de 2017):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu devo fazer para separar os nomes dos pacotes da árvore de diretórios ou criar uma classe num pacote que não seja o último?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Testes feitos na versão 2019.3.4 Community Edition.*</sup>

## Opção 1

No *Project View*, clique na engrenagem e desmarque a opção "*Compact Middle Packages*":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim, os pacotes não serão mais mostrados "juntos", e sim separadamente. Então basta clicar no pacote que você quer com o botão direito e criar a classe:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pronto, classe criada no pacote `veiculo.carro`.

Atenção: esta opção só aparece no menu se a opção "*Flatten Packages*" estiver desmarcada.

---

## Opção 2

Marcar a opção "*Flatten Packages*" e em seguida desmarcar "*Hide Empty Middle Packages*". Assim você também pode clicar em cima dos pacotes intermediários para criar a classe diretamente ali:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: ao marcar a opção "*Flatten Packages*", a opção "*Compact Middle Packages*" some do menu.

---

## Opção 3

Se você clicar no pacote, a barra de *breadcrumb* (acima do *Project View* e abaixo do menu principal) vai mostrar todos os subdiretórios relativos ao caminho do pacote, então basta clicar com o botão direito ali e criar a classe:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

## Opção 4

Por fim, outra opção - um pouco mais chatinha - é criar a classe no pacote `veiculo.carro.roda` e depois movê-la para `veiculo.carro` (clique com o botão direito na classe -> *Refactor* -> *Move class* e escolha o pacote desejado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado, não achei o botão da primeira opção mas a segunda opção me ajudou muito e até deixou a arvore de diretórios mais bonita <3

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 Eu tenho a versão 2019.3.4 Community Edition, e a opção "Compact Middle Packages" só aparece no menu se a "Flatten Packages" estiver desmarcada (se eu marcar a Flatten, a Compact some)

Comment: Enfim, não sei se tem diferença pra versões mais antigas..